# File descriptor's offset is not moving when data is read using gzFile

Tags: c, compression, gzip, zlib

I am trying to understand how glib's gzip functions works. So I wrote a small program to simulate what I need.
what I need is:
I need to open and store the file descriptor and when ever I want to just pass the fd and open a gzFile using a dupped fd and then close it. so that my original fd remains open for future read.
I've gone through lib manual [here](https://zlib.net/manual.html)!
It says that:

> "If you want to keep fd open, use fd = dup(fd_keep); gz = gzdopen(fd, mode);. The duplicated descriptor should be saved to avoid a leak, since gzdopen does not close fd if it fails."

I am doing the same as part of my below given code, where I am reading one character every time and closing the fd so that I can use it in future.

Here's My Code with gzFile that does not work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <zlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int ouFd1;

int inpFd1;

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{   
    // Open a file to write the data
    inpFd1 = open("temp.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    char* str = (char*)"Anil Prasad.";
    gzFile gzfile = gzdopen(inpFd1, "wb9h");
    int len = gzwrite(gzfile, &(str[0]), strlen(str));
    printf("written length: %d\n", len);
    gzclose(gzfile);


    // open a file to read the data.
    ouFd1 = open("temp.txt", O_RDONLY);

    char b[1]; 

    while (len > 0) { 
        int ouFd1_dup = dup(ouFd1);
        gzFile gzFile_2 = gzdopen(ouFd1_dup, "rb");
        int r = gzread(gzFile_2, &(b[0]), 1);
        printf("Character : %c\n", b[0]);
        len--;
        gzclose(gzFile_2);
    }

    fsync(ouFd1);
    close(ouFd1);
}
```

The output of this is:

> Character : A
>   Character : A
>   Character : A
>   Character : A
>   Character : A
>   Character : A
>   Character : A
>   Character : A
>   Character : A
>   Character : A
>   Character : A
>   Character : A

Can some help me understand why offset is not moving after I do a *gzread()*?
Or is it getting reset when I am doing *gzclose(gzFile_2);*?

I've tried moving offset as well like:

```
    while (len > 0) { 
        int ouFd1_dup = dup(ouFd1);
        gzFile gzFile_2 = gzdopen(ouFd1_dup, "rb");
        int r = gzread(gzFile_2, &(b[0]), 1);
        gzseek(gzFile_2, 1, SEEK_CUR);
        printf("Character : %c\n", b[0]);
        len--;
        gzclose(gzFile_2);
    }
```

But results remains same!

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You are opening and closing the file within the loop - this will reset the file pointer to the beginning on each iteration.

I don't think you need to duplicate the file descriptor for what your doing. You could just use gzopen("temp.txt", "rb") and use the file pointer given.

You are also using a buffer of size 1 - you could get the size of the file first and read into a buffer of appropriate size.

I would do something like this:

```
// Create buffer
char *buffer = new char[len+1];
memset(buffer, 0, len);

//Open file
gzFile * file = gzopen("temp.txt", "rb");
gzread(file, buffer, len);

printf("%s\n", buffer);

//Close file
gzclose(file);

//Delete buffer
delete [] buffer;
```

Comment: ok, so you mean to say that when I am closing the duplicate fd, it is reseting the offset of original fd?  
That could be possible but it does not show in glib doc.

Comment: Yes definitely. Closing the file and opening it again will position the file pointer to the beginning.

Comment: *You are opening and closing the file within the loop - this will reset the file pointer to the beginning on each iteration.*  Note that `int ouFd1_dup = dup(ouFd1);` is not going to reset the file pointer of `ouFd1_dup` as reading from a `dup()`'d file descriptor will change the offset of the original descriptor - a `dup()`'d descriptor actually refers to the **original** descriptor, so changes to the offset of `ouFd1_dup` will change the offset of `ouFd1` and the offset changes will persist past each loop iteration.  If the offset is reset, it's likely done by `gzdopen`.